# Splitting a string into exactly two parts in awk

Tags: awk

In `awk` (GNU Awk 4.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04) , what is the best way to split a string into exactly two substrings at the first occurrence of a separator character (here a `:`), leaving the second half as it is, even if it contains more separators?

---

What I currently have looks (simplified) like this (linebreaks added for visibility):

```
awk '/^[^=]+:/ { 
        split($0, a, ":") ; 
        system("echo part 1: "a[1]) ; 
        print "part 2: "a[2] ;
     }'
```

I need to call an external application with the first part as argument (using `echo` here just as an example) and print the second part as it is, without the first colon that separates part 1 and 2, but otherwise untouched.

The problem here is that the input lines likely contain more than one colon, resulting in getting split up into an array with more than two elements. With my approach above, I would simply ignore everything after the second colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the 3rd argument to `match()`:

```
$ echo 'one:two:three:four' | awk '
match($0,/([^:]+):(.*)/,a) {
    system("echo part 1: "a[1])
    print "part 2: "a[2]
}'
part 1: one
part 2: two:three:four
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `split`.  Use `index`:

```
awk '/^[^=]+:/ { 
        k=index($0, ":")
        a[1]=substr($0,1,k-1)
        a[2]=substr($0,k+1);
        system("echo part 1: "a[1]) ; 
        print "part 2: "a[2] ;
     }'
```